# What is NAME in the Python3 grammar specification

Tags: python, grammar

I wish to contribute to an open-source Python lexer. I'm looking at the official Python3 grammar specification: https://docs.python.org/3/reference/grammar.html

However, there are a lot of references to 'NAME'. For example:

```
dotted_name:
    | dotted_name '.' NAME 
    | NAME
```

I know it's something similar to an identifier but where can I find out more detail?

**What is NAME?**

Comment: I believe it's just identifiers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These are constants which represent the numeric values of leaf nodes of the parse tree (terminal tokens). See more information at [`token` — Constants used with Python parse trees](https://docs.python.org/3/library/token.html#module-token) and [Your Guide to the CPython Source Code](https://realpython.com/cpython-source-code-guide/#tokens)